# How can I reference a cell on a different sheet using a formula to determine the source location?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Excel 2016. On Sheet A, I am trying to define a range of Sheet B cells based on the contents of those cells. Sheet B has roughly 60k rows in about 250 groups based on the contents of Column A. For a given value in Column C on Sheet A, I am using successfully using something like `MATCH(C7,'Sheet B'!$A:$A,0)` to find the first row of a group and `MATCH(C7,'Sheet B'!$A:$A,1)` to find the last row. So far, so good.

Ultimately, I'm trying to use the row values determined by values in Column A above to help define a range in Column B that I can use for further evaluation. However, I think I just don't know the right way to define the column value. I've been using COUNTA as a check, and it's failing every time.

```
=COUNTA('Sheet B'!"B"&MATCH(C7,'Sheet B'!$A:$A,0):'Sheet B'!"B"&MATCH(C7,'Sheet B'!$A:$A,1)
```

Comment: Use index function to reference first and last cell. So something like this: `Counta(Index(SheetB!,topnumber,1):Index(SheetB!,bottomnumber,1)`

Comment: Do you not have `FILTER()`?

Comment: Edited post to specify that I am using Excel 2016, which apparently does not have FILTER().

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX:

```
=COUNTA(INDEX('Sheet B'!B:B,MATCH(C7,'Sheet B'!$A:$A,0)):INDEX('Sheet B'!B:B,MATCH(C7,'Sheet B'!$A:$A,1)))
```